# React-router stop lifecycle onunload

Tags: react-router

I'm using infinite scroll with React to lazy load 100's or thousands of products. Each of these products has their link to their own product page.

I am now looking to solve the usability issue where the back button is pressed it will reset the result position again, the user has to then re-scroll back to their original location, which could be thousands of items.

Initially for a moment prior to React Router triggering the React lifecycle the pure back button behaviour works as intended, it preserves the location (as it runs `window.onunload`) however after this the page proceeds to re-render and we're back to the beginning of the list as the store is recreated.

I'm looking to use onunload event as much as possible here just to implement a small convenience update without needing to remove or update the page significantly to allow for either a multi-directional lazy load and I don't wish to request 200 products on one fresh request.

Can anyone help me understand how I can situationally prevent the re-render in the case where onunload is fired (back button pressed).

Comment: Where are your storing the loaded products? Where are you storing how many you have loaded? What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm storing the loaded products after scroll in the store which grows as the infinite scroll behaviour increases. The total loaded is determined by the array size.

I'm using `2.5.1` for `react-router`.

I'm exploring checking the length of product store (before leaving) vs length of product store (after unload / on return) and if it's greater than the first visible products return false.

Comment: Would it be a possibility to keep the number of the page in state as well, which the user has reached by scrolling down, and simply render out the products from the store? While keeping track of what the next page would be. I have implemented something completely functional exactly like that.

Comment: Yeah I believe this would work in this case too. Looking now to store the page data in the URL with pushState when the product is clicked and try to block the render if the pages equal the same as what was previously in store.

Is your implementation similar to that too @ElodSzopos?

Comment: Why is the store re-created? I never had to worry about blocking a render. The underlying problem that you have might be in the history if I read correctly.

Comment: Part of store is recreated because of the route change which cleans the previous products, not the whole store. Just worked through using pushState but it's too problematic as creates too many edge cases so I'm looking at your suggestion of pushing last page as a it seems a cleaner solution.